# Cannot get debug logging to output to console

Tags: .net-core

.Net Core 2.2 - I have a library project that I've setup a logger as shown below. When I log a debug message I cannot get anything to output to console. I need help determining if the logging setup is incorrect, the configuration file or both.

```
public class TaxApi
{
    ClientOptions _clientOptions = new ClientOptions();

    void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLogging(c =>
        {
            c.AddConsole()
                .AddDebug();
                //.AddFilter<TaxService>(LogLevel.Debug.ToString());
        });
    }

    public async Task LoadSettings(string environmentName = "development")
    {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(_clientOptions.SettingsDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile(_clientOptions.SettingsFilePath, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"{_clientOptions.SettingsFileNameWithoutExtension}.{environmentName}.{_clientOptions.SettingsFileExtension}", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            var configuration = builder.Build();

            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<TaxApi>>();
            logger.LogDebug("why is this not going to the console!!!");
    }
}
```

myservice-settings.json - this is the file that gets loaded

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "TaxApi": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test console app that uses the above library.

```
class Program
{
    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await new TaxApi()
            .LoadSettings();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is writing to the console properly BUT your application terminates before the logger actually flushes and prints out the message to console. This is due to some batching effect.

Add this line after your logging statement just to verify my theory

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```